# How to test CompletableEmitter.tryOnError()

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have next code:

```
inline fun completable(crossinline action: () -> Unit) = completable(action, {})

inline fun completable(
        crossinline action: () -> Unit,
        crossinline finally: () -> Unit
): Completable {
    return Completable.create { emitter ->
        try {
            action()
            emitter.onComplete()
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            // Attempts to emit the specified {@code Throwable} error if the downstream
            // hasn't cancelled the sequence or is otherwise terminated, returning false
            // if the emission is not allowed to happen due to lifecycle restrictions.
            // <p>
            // Unlike {@link #onError(Throwable)}, the {@code RxJavaPlugins.onError} is not called
            // if the error could not be delivered.
            emitter.tryOnError(t)
        } finally {
            finally()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a test that proves error is not delivered to ErrorHandler. So I tried something like:

```
@Test
fun `Completable do not crash when terminated`() {
    var ex: Throwable? = null
    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { t -> ex = t }

    Completable.mergeArray(
            completable {
                throw IOException("test1")
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
            completable {
                throw IOException("test2")
            }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    ).onErrorComplete()
            .blockingAwait()

    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(null)

    ex?.let {
        throw it
    }
}
```

This should throw an exception if it is delivered to the handler.

Unfortunate this test is not stable. I assume multithreading is really tricky in this case.

Can I improve this test? Maybe with `TestScheduler` to simulate exactly situation that the second exception lands after the first exception terminates the stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need concurrency for this but have the consumer disposed before throwing an exception:

```java
List<Throwable> errors = new ArrayList<>();

RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(errors::add);

try {
    TestObserver<Void> to = new TestObserver<>();

    completable(() -> {
        to.dispose();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    })
    .subscribe(to);
} finally {
    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(null);
}

assertTrue(errors.isEmpty());
```

Comment: It works!  I had some issues with kotlin caching but is I do clean check it works as expected.